# export filtered results to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I have a little problem about exporting to excel some filtered results from a gridview. I used the solution from this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1991866.aspx?Export%20filtered%20results%20to%20excel%20in%20MVC%204
It all works just fine except that the table I am exporting has a lot of ID columns from foreign keys and I can't  export the numbers, I need the data. I have a variable where I keep a select join of all the tables related to the one I am exporting but I don't know how to make a connection between this variable and the one that keeps the filtered results from Session. Could you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Page_Load am displaying all the records.
2. While Exporting am selecting only the orders related to Scott

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                           if (!IsPostBack)
                           {
                               DataTable dt = BindGridView();
                               GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                               GridView1.DataBind();
                           }
             }

   ```
   private DataTable BindGridView(string name = null)
   {
       string connectionString = "Data Source=.SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Employee;Integrated Security=True";
       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
           if (name != null)
           {
               cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE Name='" + name + "'";
           }
           else
           {
               cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ORDERS";
           }

           cmd.Connection = con;
           con.Open();

           SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           dt.Load(dr);
           return dt;
       }
   }

   protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Response.Clear();
       Response.Buffer = true;
       Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=exportdata.xls");
       Response.Charset = "";
       Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
       using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
       {
           HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

           GridView gv = new GridView();
           gv.DataSource = BindGridView("Scott"); // Seelct all the order where Name='Scott' - my filter query
           gv.DataBind();

           gv.RenderControl(hw);
           Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
           Response.Flush();
           Response.End();
       }
   }

   public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
   {

   }
   ```

Comment: I have two variables. One that holds the filtered results and another one where I make join with the tables that have foreign keys with my table that I want to export. And gv.DataSource can get only one of these two, right?

Comment: Exactly, the variable which contains the filtered result set.

Comment: I put it, but the problem is that  I have some columns that are foreign keys with other tables and in this table that I want to export I only have the IDs of these columns. And I want the information, like words, not the id-s.

Comment: then you need to change the query which will get the data for the ID's and bind it in ExportToExce()

Comment: I have the variable where I get the data for the IDs. How can I use it to keep the correct export of the filtered results?

Comment: do you have the query where it gets the values instead of ID's?

Comment: var query=from a in activities
      join p in persons on a.ID_PERSON equals p.ID_PERSON
      join c in countries on a.ID_COUNTRY equals c.ID_COUNTRY
      select new { p.Name, c.Country, };

Comment: Yes, you can pass this query as DataSource to GridView in ExportToExcel and check.

Comment: I haven't succeeded in doing this. Could you write a piece of code like the one above,please?